# Improving PostgreSQL Aggregate Performance

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

What's the best way to increase the speed of a query in PostgreSQL that's performing a MAX(id) aggregation?

I have a modest number of records associated with an id, which I can COUNT() in a second e.g.

```
select count(id) as cnt from mytable where ref_id=2660

row   cnt
1     2844
```

However, when I try and find the most recent record id using MAX(), the query takes nearly 5 minutes.

```
select max(id) as id from mytable where ref_id=2660
```

This is surprising, because I've otherwise found PG surprisingly fast with much more complicated queries. Why would there be such a difference in the query times, especially for such a relatively small number of records? What would be the best way to improve this performance?

EDIT: This is the query plan for the above MAX() select:

```
"Result  (cost=219.84..219.85 rows=1 width=0)"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..219.84 rows=1 width=4)"
"          ->  Index Scan Backward using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.00..773828.42 rows=3520 width=4)"
"                Filter: ((id IS NOT NULL) AND (ref_id = 2660))"
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to add an index to 'id'

Comment: Make sure you have an index with (ref_id, id).

Comment: The (ref_id, id) index worked! Set that as your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled around, seems like PostgreSQL (up to 8.4) doesn't like `MAX` and `MIN`, it does a sequential scan of the table to get the result. It's hard to say that it's your case without the query plan and the version.

You can try this workaround.

```
SELECT id from mytable WHERE ref_id=2660 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Edit: Make sure you have an index with (ref_id, id), otherwise a table scan/sort is inevitable.

Comment: This takes about a minute to run, which is a lot faster than my query,   but still otherwise slow.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Postgres 8.4 and can say it may be a bug in Postgres optimizer to not using indexes for queries envolving min and max agregation functions.
After changing my queries from 
**Select max(field) from table** to 
**Select field from table order by field limit 1** 
my query execution time improved from 10s to less than a second.
Of course You might define and index for the column in question, otherwise postgres will do a seq_scan.